# Как умножить append элементы?

Tags: jquery

Как правильно задать это вопрос не знаю !
Имеем footer и для него надо сделать вот такой бардюр :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так как задачка не решается на css без border-image то я ради боловства решил этим заняться на js , застрял на одном моменте !
Как умножить кол-во append элементов или как это сделать более изящно ?

Собственно вопрос с [Тостер](https://toster.ru/q/458246)

Что я сделал :

```js
$(".footer").append('<div class="circle-wrapper"></div>');

$(".circle-wrapper").append('<span class="c"></span>');
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

div.circle-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  background: #fff;
}

span.c {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transform: translate(0, -3px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="footer"></div>
```

Сам один элемент добавился красного цвета , как сделать кол-во span.circle выводилось в .circle-wrapper ?

Comment: похоже что надо было border-style: dotted просто поставить

Comment: зачем всё усложнять то? это стили или просто картинка, которая повторяется. всё

Comment: @Grundy про доттед знаю .. я поизврощаться захотел - вопрос просто для практики моей

Comment: @Tsyklop возможно это решить на js без css dotted ?

Comment: конечно возможно, просто сделай цикл, в котором будешь добавлять элементы и все

Comment: @МаксимЛенский возможно но это глупо.

Comment: @Grundy не все просто. нужно просчитать их количество.

Comment: @Grundy я на цикле завис , не учил js раньше , учил плотно вёрстку и прочее что с ним связанно а теперь локти кусаю :https://codepen.io/simkaUser/pen/EvJzjj

Comment: @Tsyklop а что трудного в количестве? :-) ширина блока известна, ширина круга - тоже

Comment: @МаксимЛенский щас сделаю.

Comment: @Tsyklop, не забудь пояснения в ответе :)

Comment: может просто взять png изображение и сделать repeat по x?

Comment: @soledar10 да так проще , похоже js плохенькая идея ! хотя хотелось бы увидеть как это делается на js .... border-image конечно проще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просчитываем кол-во элементов: ширина футера / на ширину одного элемента: 7.
Делаем цикл.
P.S. оно больше получается.

```js
var count = Math.round(Math.round($(".circle-wrapper").outerWidth(true))/7);

for(var i=0;i<count;i++) {
   $(".circle-wrapper").append('<span class="c"></span>');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

div.circle-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  background: #fff;
}

span.c {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transform: translate(0, -3px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="footer"><div class="circle-wrapper"></div></div>
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский да, вижу. попробуй у себя сделать. Возможно это тут так срабатывает.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Вот. сейчас.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский я ответ обновил. у меня норм стало.

Comment: я в чате оставил скрин - не улучшилось - но твой ответ привёл меня к реализации решения

Comment: @МаксимЛенский я не могу писать в чат.

Comment: вот : https://codepen.io/simkaUser/pen/EvJzjj

Comment: @МаксимЛенский я ответил в чате.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский не совсем. убери у div.circle-wrapper overflow: hidden; и задай красный цвет. ты увидишь как оно на самом деле. тебе нужно $(".circle-wrapper").width() заменить на $(".circle-wrapper").width()/7. и в цикле сделать условие не <=, а <.

значит сам блок с таким размером. я беру ширину.

Comment: если так делать то получается что ... на маленьких экранах перехватает шариков ... а на больших не хватает , такой вариант как у меня подходит ...может и не правильный , overflow я не писал